# Reproduce random array sort

Tags: ruby, arrays, random

I have an array of objects that I want to sort by random. For this case I can use `array.shuffle`. But what if I want to reproduce that order later on the same array? Is there any way that I can provide a seed, random number, whatever, so that I can reproduce this sequence later?

I want to generate a random list of objects from a MongoDB database (using MongoID), and that list has to be reproduced later. But as far as I know, there is no really good way, to implement a random sort directly in MongoDB. There could be a lot of objects (>1,000,000), but computation time is for the first try not the fact that matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look at the [Ruby docs for `Array#shuffle`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) you'll see you can pass a `Random` as the generator; if you pass a new `Random` to shuffle using the same seed each time, it'll give the same results.

```
>> arr = %w{John Paul George Ringo}
=> ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]
>> arr.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> ["Ringo", "John", "George", "Paul"]
>> arr.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> ["Ringo", "John", "George", "Paul"]
>> arr.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> ["Ringo", "John", "George", "Paul"]
```

Edit: This can be extended to have `Array#shuffle` produce *multiple* repeatable shufflings, so that both each individual shuffle and the sequence of shufflings can be repeated, by using one `Random` (rather than a new one each time) and renewing it with the same seed to repeat:

```
>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
>> r = Random.new(17) => #<Random:0x000000017be4d0>
>> arr.shuffle(random: r) => [3, 1, 4, 2]
>> arr.shuffle(random: r) => [1, 3, 2, 4]
>> arr.shuffle(random: r) => [4, 3, 2, 1]
>> r = Random.new(17) => #<Random:0x00000001c60da8>
>> arr.shuffle(random: r) => [3, 1, 4, 2]
>> arr.shuffle(random: r) => [1, 3, 2, 4]
>> arr.shuffle(random: r) => [4, 3, 2, 1]
>> etc.
?>
```

Comment: Much nicer than my solution. Use this.

Comment: And is there a difference in the random behaviour if I use `Random.new(1)` or `Random.new(23348594949)`? Of course, this gives a different order, but is the size of the number important? And has it to be an integer, or can it be a float?

Comment: That's a different question altogether. Short answer: Size of the seed does matter, and you can pass it a float but it'll truncate it (so `3.14` gives same results as `3`).

Comment: And on 1.8? (though Joe Pym's does kind of work there :)

Comment: @rogerdpack For 1.8, I believe Joe Pym's would be the best solution. Anything else would be more complex, and would still amount to basically the same thing (unless you wanted to pull in an external random number library). However, I don't think it is thread-safe, but that's not likely to be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the source of the method (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle), it looks like it's dropping into the Ruby random number generator to sort.

If it is, you can set the seed with

```
srand *seed number*
```

before running the script. I'm not 100% on this though, it seems to work, but I'd certainly write unit tests for it!