# Randomize my record in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, random, shuffle

I created a quiz and have to randomize the questions to display using **shuffle** but when i call the next function to display next question. the order again shuffled I just want the shuffled order before controller starts and retain that in all the actions for that controller

```
private
  def shuffle(exam_group_id,student_additional_field_id)
    questions = Question.find(:all, :conditions => ['exam_group_id=? && student_additional_field_id=?',exam_group_id,student_additional_field_id]).flatten.shuffle
  end
```

Here i use the function next

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
    def start
        @user = current_user
        @student = Student.find_by_admission_no(@user.username)
        @exam_group = ExamGroup.find_by_id(params[:exam_group_id])
        @answer = Answer.new(params[:ans])
        @module = params[:student_additional_field]
        @questions = shuffle(@exam_group,@module)
        @ques = []
        @questions.each do |a|
          @ques.push a.id unless a.id.nil?
        end
        a = @ques[0]
        @s = 1
        @ans = Question.find_by_id(a)  
        render(:update) do |page|
          page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans', :object => @ans
          page.replace_html 'quespan', :partial => 'ques'
        end
      end
    def next
        @user = current_user
        @student = Student.find_by_admission_no(@user.username)
        @exam_group = ExamGroup.find_by_id(params[:exam_group_id])
        @answer = Answer.new(params[:ans])
        @answer.answer = params[:answer]
        unless params[:answer].nil?
          @answer.visited = 1
        else 
          @answer.visited = 0
        end
        @answer.exam_group_id = @exam_group.id
        @answer.user_id = @user.id
        passed_question = params[:passed_question]
        @answer.questions_id = passed_question
        @question = Question.find_by_id(passed_question)
        @module = Question.find_by_sql ["SELECT student_additional_field_id FROM questions WHERE id=#{passed_question}"]
        student_additional_field_id = @module[0].student_additional_field_id
        @s = 1 
        @questions = shuffle(@exam_group,student_additional_field_id)
        @ques = []
        @questions.each do |a|
          @ques.push a.id unless a.id.nil?
        end
        a = @ques[0] 
        @answer.modules_id = student_additional_field_id
          if params[:answer] == @question.is_answer
            @answer.marks = 1
          else
            @answer.marks = 0
          end

        if @answer.save
          @ans = Question.find_by_id(a, :conditions => [' id not in (?)',answered])
          @s = @s + answered.count
          unless @ans.nil?
            render(:update) do |page|
              page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans', :object => @ans
            end
          else
            render(:update) do |page|
              page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans2'
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

please help me out

Comment: Can you explain "next function to display next question" ?

Comment: Here i edit with next

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `shuffle` a seed, which will consistently return a result. You can pass this seed as a parameter to your `next` action. You can read more about it here: [Reproduce random array sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974992/reproduce-random-array-sort)

Modify your `shuffle` method to accept an optional seed argument, which you can then pass through in your controller, coming from a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many questions there are, I would shuffle the questions in the start action and save the order to either the session or a hidden field on the question form.

```
@questions = shuffle(@exam_group,@module)
session[:questions] = @questions.map &:id
```